How to construct a mechanical adjustment for a horizontal trim tab before the mixer on a vtail?
How to construct a mechanical adjustment for horizontal trim tabs for a vtail for:

Torque tubes/push rods?
Bungees?


The only ways I can think of are:

Torque tubes/Pushrods:

Use a turnbuckle with a handle to adjust the length of the push rod/torque tube in-between the control stick and the mixer

Bungees:

Add an idler pulley wheel that can be adjusted to increase/decrease the tension in the bungee between the control stick and the mixer.

I'm having difficulty reconciling this question and answer with your other one...
